Make an application that consumes an API and prevent the user from consuming the same API without using the aplication
Let's say I make a game that has a public online score board.
The game would have to send requests to an external public API that has access to the database where the scores are stored.
How could I prevent the player from sending fake scores to the API by simulating the same requests that the game does?

Depends on the amount of effort you want to go through. In the case of a game, monitoring the events of the game server side and detecting for impossible actions I would think to be the most full proof. If the events align with the score you can accept it otherwise reject.
